# How can I extract text before a specific character in a string using Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a string that looks like:

`5137.02014-10-16T11:26:32-06:001.0`.

How can I extract the text or numbers before the first period? It will not always be 4 characters.

**EDIT:**

After looking at the source code, it appears to be producing this:

```
<wddxpacket version="1.0">
  <header>
   <data>
     <struct>
     <var name="Logo">
       <string></string>
     </var>
     <var name="ID">
       <number>5137.0</number>
     </var>
     <var name="RLink">
       <string></string>
     </var>
     <var name="DateCreated">
       <datetime>2014-10-16T11:26:32-06:00</datetime>
     </var>
     <var name="showTabs">
       <number>1.0</number>
     </var>
    </struct>
</data>
```

I am just trying to extract the ID which would be 5137 in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that result something your app generates? Because returning JSON would be more flexible than WDDX.

Comment: This was created as a cookie. You can see the raw cookie here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/12513d6d5193553e8076

Comment: See my updated answer. BTW, just curious - what code generates that cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Looks like the input is actually WDDX, rather than a plain text string. Convert it into a CF structure. Then extract the "ID" value by key. No need for parsing strings.

```
<!--- convert the string into a CF structure --->
<cfwddx action="WDDX2CFML" 
    input="#yourString#" 
    output="result">

<!--- grab the "ID" value --->
<cfdump var="#result.ID#">
```

Comment: Touche! :) Although, you say "if the element will always contain a period". That's not a concern here as this isn't a complex string, he's just wanting slice off a decimal. ListFirst(string_with_no_decimal,".") is just treated as a one element string.  Since you showed him to pull a variable out of wddx properly, there's no concern for it to contain more data like a date. Know what I mean? `<cfset num = 523723><cfset num2 = listfirst(num,".")><cfoutput>#num2#</cfoutput>`. Also, now that we know the string is a valid number, he can probably just use Int().

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Haha. Actually I said "string" :P  That was from my original answer, when we still thought it was a simple string. I deleted it, because there is no point in multiple answers saying the same thing. I later "undeleted" my answer, when the wddx stuff came to light, and appended a new answer. (Note the timestamps) Guess I did not make the "update" obvious enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

With updated information on the structure of the data, this answer is no longer valid.

---

You can do this

```
#listfirst(my_number_string,".")#
```

Comment: Beat me by ten seconds ;-) Deleting my answer to avoid dupes. Trey - if the string will always contain a certain character, a simple option is to treat it as a list delimited by that character: case a period ".".

Comment: I could never get this to work: `<cfoutput>affid = #ListFirst(variables.gaAffiliateID,".")#</cfoutput>`. It would always show up as blank.

Comment: (Edit) Works fine with the sample string you posted. What is the actual value of variables.gaAffiliateID?

Comment: `5137.02014-10-16T11:26:32-06:001.0`

Comment: What is the value of variables.gaAffilateID when you try this?  What are you looking at that shows up as blank?

Comment: @TreyCopeland Edit your question and provide some code. There's no reason this shouldn't work based on the string you provided.

Comment: *would always show up as blank* That suggests your `variables.gaAffilateID` value is actually an empty string.

Comment: i have modified the code. i failed to see the actual html in the source the first time.